# jQuery - How can I bind a button element to a particular select element?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby

I have an ruby-based application which manages people and their subscriptions. I have a search form in it that allows an admin to search for every person with multiple specified subscriptions.

This form uses a `<select>` box to select a subscription and has `+` and `-` symbols to dynamically add and remove `<select>` boxes, like so:

[image: subscription search]

The way the jQuery is set up, if I click any `+` button, it will clone the *first* `<select>` box and the *first* `+` and `-` button and then append that clone to the end of the list.

Similarly, clicking any `-` button removes the *last* item.

What I want to do is have the buttons act on the select box in the same row. So, if I click the `-` button on the second row, it should delete the second row. Similarly, clicking the second `+` button should append a new row right after the second row.

My jQuery:

```
$('.add-button').click(function(event){
    $subscriptionSelectionList = $('#subscription-select-list');
    $subscriptionSelectionBox = $('.subscription-select-box:first');

    $subscriptionSelectionBox.clone(true).appendTo($subscriptionSelectionList);

    $subscriptionSelectionRemoveButtons = $('.remove-button');

    // Show remove buttons if there is more than one element
    if ($subscriptionSelectionList.children("li").length > 1) {
        $subscriptionSelectionRemoveButtons.show();
    }
}) // End function to add extra selections

// Function to dynamicaly remove subscription search boxes
$('.remove-button').click(function(event){
    $subscriptionSelectionList = $('#subscription-select-list');
    $subscriptionSelectionBox = $('.subscription-select-box:last');

    $subscriptionSelectionBox.remove();

    $subscriptionSelectionRemoveButtons = $('.remove-button');

    // Hide remove buttons if there is only one element
    if ($subscriptionSelectionList.children("li").length == 1) {
        $subscriptionSelectionRemoveButtons.hide();
    }
}) // End function to remove extra selections
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="subscription-select-list">
    <li class="subscription-select-box">
        <select name="search[subscriptions][]">
            <option value="">Select a subscription</option>
            <% @products.each do |product| %>
                <optgroup label="<%= product.name %>">
                    <% product.subscriptions.each do |subscription| %>
                        <option value="<%= subscription.id %>"><%= subscription.name %></option>
                    <% end %>
                </optgroup>
            <% end %>
        </select>
        <img src="/img/add_circle.png" alt="Circular add button" class="add-button">
        <img src="/img/remove_circle.png" alt="Circular add button" class="remove-button" style="display: none;">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest("li.subscription-select-box").find("select")`

Comment: Thanks @Andreas ! This worked perfectly! And I only needed to change a few lines of code :D. If you can make it an answer, I can mark it as best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse the DOM from the clicked button up to the closest `<li>` element and from there to the corresponding `<ul>` with [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
// this is the clicked "button"
var theListItem = $(this).closest("li.subscription-select-box");
var theList = theListItemForTheClickedButton.closest("ul");
```

---

Regarding the snippet:

- I've replaced your images with buttons, but this has no effect on the script itself.
- The CSS part in the snippet below is not relevant for the answer and is only used to adopt your styling.
- The `.fadeOut()` part is only to show that the correct list item is removed.

```js
$("#subscription-select-list").on("click", ".add-button", function() {
  var $subscriptionSelectionBox = $(this).closest("li.subscription-select-box"),
      $subscriptionSelectionList = $(this).closest("ul");
      // or $subscriptionSelectionList = $subscriptionSelectionBox.closest("ul");
      // or $subscriptionSelectionList = $subscriptionSelectionBox.parent();

  $subscriptionSelectionBox.clone(true).appendTo($subscriptionSelectionList);

  if ($subscriptionSelectionList.children("li").length > 1) {
    $subscriptionSelectionList.find(".remove-button").show();
  }
});

$("#subscription-select-list").on("click", ".remove-button", function() {
  var $subscriptionSelectionBox = $(this).closest("li.subscription-select-box"),
      $subscriptionSelectionList = $(this).closest("ul");

  // fadeOut is just to show that the "clicked" select is removed
  $subscriptionSelectionBox.fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove();

    if ($subscriptionSelectionList.children("li").length <= 1) {
      $subscriptionSelectionList.find(".remove-button").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul { list-style: none }
select, button { padding: 5px; border: solid 1px #a9a9a9; border-radius: 5px; }
select { width: 300px; background-color: #fff }
button { width: 30px; color: white; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer }
button.add-button { background-color: #4ebd93; }
button.remove-button { background-color: #d12e3b }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="subscription-select-list">
  <li class="subscription-select-box">
    <select name="search[subscriptions][]">
      <option value="">Select a subscription</option>
      <optgroup label="Product 1">
        <option value="1.1">Subscription 1.1</option>
        <option value="1.2">Subscription 1.2</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
    <button type="button" class="add-button">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="remove-button" style="display:none">-</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I ended up using the fade effects as well to show which ones were added and removed :). Thanks!

Comment: Just one thing that I just noticed here. The if statement at the end (which hides the remove buttons), should be placed within the .fadeOut() function or else it doesn't work. Just mentioned this in case it helps anyone else! :)

Comment: @UmarGhouse You're absolutely right. I don't know how I missed that... I've fixed the snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/u1ou0nyq/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-button', function(){
  var clone = $(this).closest('li.subscription-select-box').clone();
  $('#subscription-select-list').append(clone);
  if( $('#subscription-select-list').children().length > 1) {
   $('li.subscription-select-box').find('.remove-button').show();
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-button', function(){
  $(this).closest('li.subscription-select-box').remove();
  if( $('#subscription-select-list').children().length === 1) {
   $('li.subscription-select-box').find('.remove-button').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.remove-button {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="subscription-select-list">
  <li class="subscription-select-box">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <div class="add-button">
    +
    </div>
    <div class="remove-button">
    -
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As the elements are dynamically generated, you need to delegate the `events`.

Check number of `li` everytime, whenever delete or add is happening.

Please change the delete & add `div` to your `image` tag.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Specify add and remove image button 's unique id by adding dynamic value my managing variable.

Ex.      // must increase i in loop.

Now on click event you have parameter i and find out element with "btnAdd" + i and add element after it.

On remove click, remove same element.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do in this case is something like this:

```js
$('.add-button').click(function(event){
    $(this).parent().clone().appendTo($this.parent());
});

$('.remove-button').click(function(event){ 
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
.subscription-select-box:only-child .remove-button {
  display: none;
}
```

And add this simple css to control the remove button visibility if there's only one select.

Comment: I "Run code snippet"  and I see Error: { "message": "'$' is undefined","filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js","lineno": 15, "colno": 9}

Comment: Sorry, @ErezZrihen. I accidentally posted as a snippet instead of just a sample code.

Comment: oh I understand.